# Why does TS compile differently when property is not initialized

Tags: typescript

```
export class test{
     foo: Boolean;
     bar: Boolean = undefined;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
export class Test {
constructor() {
    this.bar = undefined;
}
```

}

Note that `foo` does not become a property.

Is this a bug in Typescript?

This bit me today because the binding framework I use (Aurelia) works with the bar example, but not with foo.

It seems to me that foo should automatically be created as a property like bar is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a bug. Since `test.foo` is `undefined` either way (which is usually the only thing you care about), it doesn't make sense to use up more memory and time doing something that's usually pointless.

Not initializing the property automatically lets you choose the behavior you want: If you want an own property (because someone is calling `Object.keys` or equivalent on your class instance), initialize it. If you don't (because you want to save memory and time), don't.

Comment: Actually, there are plenty of reasons - for one, an observable behavior is when `foo in obj` is called. For another - declaring properties up front in modern engines is typically much faster because of how JITs work.